# SQLAlchemy converts Password to HEX Value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sanic

I'm using Sanic + SQLAlchemy for a project of mine.

Basically, I have this endpoint which is used for registering an user

```
from sanic import Blueprint, response
from sanic.request import Request
from sanic.response import HTTPResponse
import bcrypt
import logging
from sanic_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from services.userservice import create_user, find_by_username


@bp.route("/add",methods=["POST", "OPTIONS"])
@cross_origin(bp, origins='*',automatic_options=True)
async def register(req: Request) -> HTTPResponse:
    """
    Register the user in the system
    :param req: the request sent from the user. Will contain the necessary parameters to save the user in the system
    :return 200 if the user is registered, 500 if an error happens
    """
    LOGGER.info(">>>>>> /user/add")
    chosen_username = req.json['utente']['username']
    chosen_pwd = req.json['utente']['password']
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt(rounds = 10, prefix=b"2a")
    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(chosen_pwd.encode('utf-8'), salt)
    insert_success = await create_user(chosen_username,hashed,req.app.session_pgsql)
    if insert_success:
        LOGGER.info(f"[{chosen_username}] successfully created!")
        created_user = await find_by_username(chosen_username, req.app.session_pgsql)
        return response.json({'status': 200, 'message': 'OK', 'data': created_user}, 200)
    else:
        LOGGER.error(f"Couldn't add {chosen_username} to the database!")
        return response.json({'status':500, 'message': 'ERROR', 'data': None},500)
```

The bcrypt instantiates the salt in that way because the authentication process is carried by a Java Microservice. 
Then, when the code reaches the create_user method

```
async def create_user(chosen_username: str, hashed: str, session_pgsql: Session) -> bool:
    """
    Creates the specified user in the database
    :param chosen_username: the chosen username
    :param hashed: the hashed password that the new user chose
    :param session_pgsql: the SQLAlchemy Session Object that will insert the user in the DB
    :return True if the insert was successful, False otherwhise
    """
    new_user = Utente(username=chosen_username, pwd=hashed)
    session_pgsql.add(new_user)
    try:
        session_pgsql.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        session_pgsql.rollback()
        return False
    return True
```

The save operation goes smoothly but, in my *PostgreSQL* database (the connection is made with the postgresql+psycopg2 driver URL configuration), I see the password saved as a sequence of hex characters.
Even if, for example, I try to

```
session_pgsql.query(Utente).filter(Utente.id == new_user.id).update({Utente.pwd : hashed}, synchronize_session = False)
```

or

```
new_user.pwd = hashed
session_pgsql.commit()
```

in debug mode with PyCharm, the password is still shown as a sequence of hex characters.
Does somebody might have a vague clue of what's going on? As far as I've seen in the debug, the password arrives correctly to the create_user method, so I assume the problem must rely inside SQLAlchemy

The Utente model is a class like this

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

"""
The ORM class that represents the 'Utente' table 
"""
class Utente(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'utente'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

   username = Column(String, unique=True)
   pwd = Column(String)
   enabled = Column(Boolean, default=False)
   first_access_done = Column(Boolean, default=False)
```

EDIT: As requested, here's what happens to my data. 
Right before the commit on the database, the Utente object looks like this.

```
new_user.username
Out[4]: 'acooltestmail@gmail.com'
In[5]: 
new_user.pwd
Out[5]: b'$2a$10$WhF2CBCCm1MLaoOlwRx4YeA.uMQNtL3XHOI6i09ZbWkKDp5hxA2Fe'
```

Then, this query is executed by SQLAlchemy

```
2020-06-05 20:27:02,973 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2020-06-05 20:27:03,016 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO utente (username, pwd, enabled, first_access_done) VALUES (%(username)s, %(pwd)s, %(enabled)s, %(first_access_done)s) RETURNING utente.id
2020-06-05 20:27:03,016 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'username': 'acooltestmail@gmail.com', 'pwd': b'$2a$10$WhF2CBCCm1MLaoOlwRx4YeA.uMQNtL3XHOI6i09ZbWkKDp5hxA2Fe', 'enabled': False, 'first_access_done': False}
2020-06-05 20:27:03,037 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

But if I go to see the result query in the database, this is what the result actually looks like

```
id|username              |pwd                                                                                                                       |enabled|first_access_done|
--|----------------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------|-----------------|
 5|acooltestmail@gmail.com|\x2432612431302457684632434243436d314d4c616f4f6c775278345965412e754d514e744c3358484f49366930395a62576b4b447035687841324665|false  |false            |
```

Comment: Please provide the `Utente` model. Hashes are usually binary data, unless you encode them somehow. PostgreSQL *displays* binary data using a hex representation. Python displays binary strings in a mixed fashion.

Comment: @IljaEverilä done! Sorry about that

Comment: Could you also provide, as text, the exact representation you get in PostgreSQL and in Python?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Done! The query seems correct, but I believe now that maybe the problem is PostgreSQL...

Comment: Hmm ok, I think I might understand. You've defined `Utente.pwd` to have text type, but you send the result of bcrypt, which is binary, as is. I think PostgreSQL then happily stores the text representation of that binary, which you then get back when querying. Will have to check if this is the case.

Comment: @IljaEverilä hmm not quite... Because if I query session_pgsql.query(Utente).filter().first().pwd after the commit, what I get is actually the password like it is in the database :(

Comment: "Like it is" being `b'$2a$10$WhF2CBCCm1MLaoOlwRx4YeA.uMQNtL3XHOI6i09ZbWkKDp5hxA2Fe'` or `'\\x24326124313024576846...`?

Comment: @IljaEverilä the second option. After the user is saved, the password will always be received like in the second option

Comment: Aye, it's as I thought. You're sending the hash binary content, PostgreSQL casts it to text implicitly – due to the column having text type – in its own way and stores the result.

Comment: @IljaEverilä do you know if there is any way to avoid this?

Comment: Since you're using bcrypt, I guess I'd suggest changing your DB schema to suit and using a binary column instead of text to store the result. On the other hand the contents of that binary seem like ASCII text, so you could decode it as such and store the resulting text, but please check if it really is that. Note that if you decide to store it as text, you have to encode it back to binary before passing to `bcrypt.checkpw()`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä solved, see my own answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it happened to be an error by my side. 
The doubt came to me when I saw that the result of the bcrypt's hash, in the debugger, was rendered as b'$2a$10$WhF2CBCCm1MLaoOlwRx4YeA.uMQNtL3XHOI6i09ZbWkKDp5hxA2Fe'. 
I believed that bcrypt's `hashpw` method returned a `string`, while it actually returns a `bytes` object. Thus, if saved to a `PostgreSQL` `varchar` field, the database tries to conver the value to an actual string (like Ilja Everilä was suggesting in the comments).